# Valgrind about asprintf: address is 0 bytes inside a block of size <size> alloc'd

Tags: c, linux, valgrind, asprintf

I have some code like this:

```
void logConnectionStatus(char * domain, char * status, mqd_t logQueue) {
    char * message;
    asprintf(&message, "Connection to domain %s: %s", domain, status);
    mq_send(logQueue, message, 1024, 0);
    free(msg);
}
```

but valgrind check says that

> Address 0x566c0f5 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 53 alloc'd

What can be the reason? Thank you.

Comment: what is `message` ?

Comment: I think you mean: `mq_send(logQueue, msg, strlen(msg), 0);`

Comment: On which line does Valgrind say that there is an error?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sorry, it was copy-paste mistake, fixed.

Comment: @PaulFloyd It says first: Syscall param mq_timedsend(msg_ptr) points to unaddressable byte(s), and then the message in my question. Right at the line with asprintf.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre strlen() instead of fixed size is the correct solution, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(that is assuming you mean `mq_send(logQueue, msg, 1024, 0);` since `message` is nowhere to be found here)

`asprintf` call is okay (unless `domain` or `status` are corrupt/null pointers).

But right afterwards, you're sending a message of size `1024`, probably way beyond the `msg` string size (since `domain` and `status` are probably human-readable short strings).

You should note down the number of printed characters that `asprintf` returns and use that in the next call:

```
char * msg;
int nb_printed = asprintf(&msg, "Connection to domain %s: %s", domain, status);
mq_send(logQueue, msg, nb_printed, 0);
free(msg);
```

Comment: The problem was really with sending buffer size. After I changed it from 1024 to strlen(message) the problem disappeared. Thanks for your answer!